# Save and load text file with array of structures

Tags: c, file

So i have been assigned by my teacher to create a pharmacy program that can store structures of drugs in a large register array. So far everything is going well the program itself if done. Now i need to make it so that when i open up the program it asks for a file name, if the filename doesnt exist it will begin with a new .txt file, it it already exists its simply gonna read from the choosen file. When the users quits the program its gonna write over already existing .txt file or just simple write on the .txt file if it didnt already exist.

```
void readFromFile(Lakemedel lakemedelRegister[],int *pNrOfLakemedel, char *filnamn)
{
FILE *infil;
printf("Infilens namn? ");
scanf(" %s", filnamn);
infil = fopen(filnamn, "r");

if(infil == NULL)
   {
      printf("Ny fil skapas\n");                
   }
else
    {
        fscanf(infil,"%d",*pNrOfLakemedel);
        for(int i = 0; i<*pNrOfLakemedel; i++)
        {
            int sistastorlek;
            fscanf(infil, "%s",lakemedelRegister[i].namn);
            for(int j = 0; j<sistastorlek; j++)
            {
                fscanf(infil, "%d",lakemedelRegister[i].storlekar[j]);
                lakemedelRegister[i].NrOfstorlekar ++;
                if(lakemedelRegister[i].storlekar[j]==0)
                {
                    j=sistastorlek;
                }
            }
            for(int k = 0; k<sistastorlek; i++)
            {
                fscanf(infil,"%d",lakemedelRegister[i].saldo[k]);
            }

        }
        fclose(infil);
    }


}

void save(Lakemedel lakemedelRegister[],int *pNrOfLakemedel,char filnamn[])
{
    FILE *infil = fopen(filnamn,"w");
   if(infil == NULL)
   {
      printf("Ny fil skapas\n");                
   }
    else
    {
        fprintf(infil,"%d",*pNrOfLakemedel);
        for(int i = 0; i<*pNrOfLakemedel; i++)
        {
            int sistastorlek;
            fprintf(infil, "%s",lakemedelRegister[i].namn);
            for(int j = 0; j<sistastorlek; j++)
            {
                fprintf(infil, "%d",lakemedelRegister[i].storlekar[j]);
                lakemedelRegister[i].NrOfstorlekar ++;
                if(lakemedelRegister[i].storlekar[j]==0)
                {
                    j=sistastorlek;
                }
            }
            for(int k = 0; k<sistastorlek; i++)
            {
                fprintf(infil,"%d",lakemedelRegister[i].saldo[k]);
            }

        }
    }
   fclose(infil);
```

I dont get any compiling errors, the program creates a txt file but the next time i open the program and give the name of the already created txt file it just crashes or stops working.
I've done all the cody myself trying to copy over every drug's structure members over to the new text file but i dont know if im on the right way. My programming book (swedish) also doesn't cover this area quite well, atleast not with array of structures to be copied. Appreciate all the help i can get!

Comment: Please make a [mre] of the program you are describing.

Comment: `fscanf(infil,"%d",*pNrOfLakemedel)` should be `fscanf(infil,"%d",pNrOfLakemedel)`. Suggest you run your program in a debugger. At a minimum it will tell you immediately which line causes the crash. And you can use it to step thru the program execution.